# How do I embed GroupBoxes in a ListView?

Tags: c#, listview, controls, groupbox

I have numerous groupboxes that need to be listed in a ListView.

I have tried:

listView1.Controls.Add(new NewsBox());

(NewsBox being a custom class derived from GroupBox, just with standard labels and a definite size)

Anyways, that works for listing the first controlbox, but not for 2 or more.

Any ideas?

Comment: No, this can't work.  ListView is not a container control.  FlowLayoutPanel is.

Comment: The only grouping mechanism you can use in a `ListView` is `ListViewGroup` (not a control).

Comment: Retagged without the EMBEDDED tag as this question does not apply to embedded computing.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work. You can't have multiple GroupBoxes in a ListView control.

To add things to a ListView, use myListView.Items.Add(...).